# TYPO3 DataProcessing: How to control the order of the output?

Tags: typo3, typoscript

I have a list with content uids from a mask custom content element. The editor can choose some content elements from a list. And now I want the complete data from these content element uids. So I tried DatabaseQueryProcessor.

I am trying with DataProcessing for the first time.

```
dataProcessing {
    10 = TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\DataProcessing\DatabaseQueryProcessor
    10 {
        table = tt_content          
        uidInList.field = tx_mask_sectionmenu_contentitems    
        as = items
    }
}
```

This almost works, but the order in fluid output does not match the order of the original list. How can I force the same order for the fluid output as in the original list?

Or do I have to go over the SplitProcessor first?
This SplitProcessor works so far, but I don’t know what to specify in the next DatabaseQueryProcessor?

```
dataProcessing {

    10 = TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\DataProcessing\SplitProcessor
    10 {
        if.isTrue.field = tx_mask_sectionmenu_contentitems
        delimiter = ,
        fieldName = tx_mask_sectionmenu_contentitems
        removeEmptyEntries = 1
        filterIntegers = 0
        filterUnique = 1
        as = items

        dataProcessing {
          10 = TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\DataProcessing\DatabaseQueryProcessor
          10 {
            table = tt_content                          
            ???
            as = contentItem
          }
       }
    }        
}
```

The sorting field is not what I want. I want the same sorting like the editor has selected.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 3):

As far as I can see, the SplitProcessor does not support any further dataProcessing like other DataProcessors (at least if haven't noticed any dataProcessing on the list of options like for others): https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-typoscript/main/en-us/ContentObjects/Fluidtemplate/DataProcessing/SplitProcessor.html

Here is a workaround, that also works with TYPO3 11:

https://forge.typo3.org/issues/86151

In short:

```
dataProcessing {
    10 = TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\DataProcessing\DatabaseQueryProcessor
    10 {
        table = tt_content                          
        uidInList.field = tx_mask_sectionmenu_contentitems
        selectFields.dataWrap = *,FIND_IN_SET(uid,'{field:pages}') AS foobar_sort
orderBy = foobar_sort

        as = contentItem
    }
}
```

Comment: Wonderful answer. Works even in TYPO3 8.7.x :-)

Answer (score 1):

I tested `uidInList.field = tx_mask_sectionmenu_contentitems` but it doesn't helped to get the records sorted by the order of the comma-separated uid list.

The nested approach doesn't worked at all. I had a look in the code and found that only `DatabaseQueryProcessor`, `LanguageMenuProcessor` and `MenuProcessor` are able to process the content with another MenuProcessor.

Answer (score 0):

According to https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-typoscript/master/en-us/ContentObjects/Fluidtemplate/Index.html#dataprocessing

```
  # All properties from .select can be used directly
  # + stdWrap
  colPos = 1
  pidInList = 13,14
```

and checking the select properties https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-typoscript/master/en-us/Functions/Select.html gives you

```
  uidInList =
  pidInList =
  recursive =
  orderBy =
  groupBy =
  max =
  begin =
  where =
  languageField =
  includeRecordsWithoutDefaultTranslation =
  selectFields =
  join =
  leftjoin =
  rightjoin =
```

So instead of using nested `dataProcessing` here, you might want to skip `orderBy` and go for `uidInList` instead.

```
  uidInList.field = tx_mask_sectionmenu_contentitems
```

If you want to stay with the nested approach, you should still use uidInList, but slightly different

```
dataProcessing {
    10 = TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\DataProcessing\SplitProcessor
    10 {
        if.isTrue.field = tx_mask_sectionmenu_contentitems
        delimiter = ,
        fieldName = tx_mask_sectionmenu_contentitems
        removeEmptyEntries = 1
        filterIntegers = 0
        filterUnique = 1
        as = items

        dataProcessing {
          10 = TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\DataProcessing\DatabaseQueryProcessor
          10 {
            table = tt_content                          
            uidInList.field = current
            as = contentItem
          }
       }
    }        
}
```

To get the actual field name for "current" you might want to put `<f:debug>{items}</f:debug>` into your Fluid template. Maybe it has to be `data = current` instead, if the actual behaviour of `current` is available in this context.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!
I first tried this, see my first code example. I just get the uids of the content elements. Sure I can loop in fluid over the uids with for example VHS to get the content of the elements. But I would like to do that before and not in the fluid. If that does not work, I'll probably have to find another solution or I try a more complicated fluid solution.

Comment: I just added the full dataProcessing block - if you just get the uids, there must be something wrong with your setup, since the query processor should return full tt_content records

Comment: A dirty workaround in the old days of TYPO3 was

orderBy.dataWrap = FIND_IN_SET({field:myField})

But I dont't think this is still working with Doctrine under the hood.

Comment: You're right. The first code snippet gives me the full tt_content records, but with the not wanted "sorting" order. That's why I thought that a split-processor between would be helpful :-). I've tried so much, I do not remember what :-).

Comment: I have exactly the same problem as Lukas described with TYPO3 9.5 and the uidInList approach. The order in the field is correct. But the output is in wrong order and not as selected in be.